# Is there some Android app to scroll/zoom battery history?

Tags: android, battery

Because sometimes when I am analyzing wakelocks and trying to figure out if an app after changing some settings keeps my phone awake or not gets pretty difficult after a few hours of battery history reset. The graph is suddenly trying to fit an extended period of time on a small screen and it is really hard to determine the awake/screen on/etc. bars where they start and end.

I would like to see e.g. when it started to be on/off, scroll in time or such. This seem like a pretty obvious feature to me and the data is there, but I cannot manipulate the view efficiently enough.

Is there an app or some modification I can use to see the battery history in a more information rich way?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : - http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-battery-history-xxl-v0-1-t2897681 or  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector&hl=en

Comment: I already use wakelock detector, to figure out which app is wakelocking how much. However, I need to know When.WLD sums up the amount of time spent awake due to an app and you cannot tell when exactly was which app responsible for the WL. So I was trying to deduce app responsibility based on timespan of awake state from the battery history. But the time of a WL is extremely hard to read from android native graph. See here: http://goo.gl/nfGzpW It is very hard to tell the exact times of different events. Graph is unreadable. The other link w/ increased number of apps is not targeting my issue.